# Can I return exception in positive situation?

Tags: python, exception

I would like to create simple code without checking if method returns `True`.

```
    try:
        self.__verify_headers(request)
        self.__has_mguid(request)
        self.__verify_devices_counter(request, course)
        self.__save_device(request, course)
    except NoAdditionalHeaderException, KeyError:
        raise Exception("No additional headers in request")
    except DeviceExistException:
        return True
```

method `__has_mguid` throw exception `DeviceExistException`

Is this a right approach? I don't want put ugly code something like:

```
if True == self.__has_mguid(request):
   return True
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do that. See [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

*There are (at least) two distinguishable kinds of errors: syntax errors and exceptions.*

and

*Errors detected during execution are called exceptions*

So exceptions are errors. They occur when something goes wrong, not when something went as expected.

---

*I don't want put ugly code something like:*

```
if True == self.__has_mguid(request): 
    return True
```

---

Instead of that you can do this:

```
return self.__has_mguid(request)
```

If `self.__has_mguid(request)` is `True`, it will return `True`, if it's `False`, it will return `False`

Comment: You're suggested code doesn't do exactly the same he should use

`   if self.__has_mguid(request): `
`        return True`
To get the same functionality, because on false he executes 2 more functions.